# PHP - sort by numerical order

Tags: php, sorting, foreach, directory, glob

Im trying to sort the items inside /folders by numerical order but they are ordered like this:
[image]

```
 foreach(glob('C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\central/folders/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
    $dir = basename($dir);
    $button = "<button class='items' >$dir</a></button>";
    echo $button;
    
}
```

Thank y'all in advance.

Comment: Where do you sort?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the files/directories as the filesystem sorts them.  You need a natural sort:

```
$directories = glob('C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\central/folders/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
natsort($directories);
//or
//sort($directories, SORT_NATURAL);

//foreach($directories as $dir)
```